# Mozilla cannot launch on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, mozilla

I upgraded Ubuntu from to 20.04, and was using Firefox with no issues.  Then randomly one day I got opened a link in a new tab, and got a page not found Firefox needs to restart.  So I clicked restart and then Firefox will not open.  I have tried to uninstall Firefox, and still it won't launch.  I am getting a crash report and have reported it.

Some of the things that I have tried:

- Reinstalling through the terminal with the following commands sudo apt remove firefox
- run sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys A6DCF7707EBC211FD
- Install firefox with the following command sudo apt install firefox
- Run the following command:  firefox --version which returns Mozilla Firefox 86.0

I am not sure what else I need to do?  I am fairly new to linux and ubunut, and I have done research trying to figure out the solution...and haven't found it.

The alternatives that I have found are to install Chrome-(which I am using) or opera.  If that is the permanent solution then so be it, but I wanted to see if the problem can be fixed.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: What do you get by running Firefox on the terminal?

Comment: I still get an option for the crash report...it still does not launch.

I get the following in the terminal:
ExceptionHandler::GenerateDump cloned child 37857
ExceptionHandler::SendContinueSignalToChild sent continue signal to child
ExceptionHandler::WaitForContinueSignal waiting for continue signal...

After typing firefox in the terminal

Comment: This may help https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1222053

Comment: @yang, why would you think an answer of 2 years ago will help?

Answer (score 0):

You may be victim of a bug in the latest Firefox 86.0, which does not seem to affect too may people, though. According to this support thread, the issue, "bug 1694670", would be solved in 87.b03, but hopefully will also be solved very soon in a dot release of 86.0.

For now, the only solution may be to [downgrade](https://sourcedigit.com/24525-ubuntu-downgrade-package-to-previous-version/) to the previous version of Firefox until an update fixes the issue for you.